Stable timestep criterion for variable density acoustic wave equation
As part of my PhD, I am implementing the isotropic variable density acoustic wave equation numerically with finite-difference and I have a question regarding its stable timestep criterion.
The variable density acoustic wave equation in 3D is given by,
$\frac{1}{\rho c^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}} = \nabla \cdot(\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla u)$
where $\rho$ is the density, $c$ is the velocity, and $u$ is the pressure.
When seeking to derive the stable timestep required for a simple central difference implementation of this but in the case that density is constant, the answer to this can be readily found in textbooks or online resources to be,
$\Delta t < \frac{1}{c\sqrt{\frac{1}{\Delta x^{2}}+\frac{1}{\Delta y^{2}}+\frac{1}{\Delta z^{2}}}}$
However, how does this stable timestep criterion change in the case of variable density? If at all? Are there any extra restrictions required on density (other than being non-zero) to ensure that the solution is stable?

WHen the density is allowed to be variable, there will be an additional $\nabla(1/\rho)\cdot \nabla u$ term on the right-hand side. Try to follow whatever derivation you found online whilst including this term and see what happens.
